# Divide by Zero issues

Tags: sql-server-2012

I keep getting divide by zero errors. I've read a few answers around here, but maybe I'm using it in the wrong way.
Any help is appreciated.

See what I currently have here:

```
,cast(round((((Select JCCM.ContractAmt)
    -
((Select (sum (JCCP.CurrEstCost))
    From JCCP
    Where JCCP.Job = JCCM.Contract)))
    /
(Select JCCM.ContractAmt) *100),2) as numeric (36,2)) as 'Estimated Gross Profit (Loss) %'
```

THANKS!

Comment: What result do you want to send back in case the denominator were hypothetically zero?

Comment: Confirm that `JCCM.ContractAmt` are all non-zero values, or do a `ISNULL` on the denominator.

Comment: Tim, if the value is 0, return '-' or 0%
Rudy, not all are zero, only a few are

Comment: (Select JCCM.ContractAmt) *100),2) as numeric (36,2))  must be returning 0, or the rounding of it is 0. Why are you rounding it before the cast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm that JCCM.ContractAmt are all non-zero values

or do a ISNULL on the denominator

or add this in the `WHERE`; either `ISNULL` or `JCCM.ContractAmt > 0`

Comment: So stupid. I never thought of the where clause >0. THANKS! That did work. But I'd like it to show even if 0. How would I place the isnull properly?

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess JCCM.ContractAmt is the contract amount, so if the contract amount is `0` then 'Estimated Gross Profit (Loss) %' must be zero (assuming the company did not have any `CurrEstCost` before having a contract amount).

So you could wrap this in a case statement, like this:

```
, CASE ISNULL(JCCM.ContractAmt,0)=0 THEN 0
       ELSE
         cast(round((((Select JCCM.ContractAmt)
         -
         ((Select (sum (JCCP.CurrEstCost))
         From JCCP
         Where JCCP.Job = JCCM.Contract)))
         /
         (Select JCCM.ContractAmt) *100),2) as numeric (36,2)) 
   END
as 'Estimated Gross Profit (Loss) %'
```